# How to extract number from backwards in javascript in optimised way

Tags: javascript

I have to extract a string from backwards upto 10 digits. 
Use case is when we select a mobile number it is prefixed with country code sometimes and sometimes we get only the mobile number.

Let's say the number is : `+91-84040355236545`
I have to extract the number from the end say from 5 to last 10 degits so the end result would be `0355236545`

I have a solution of using string.substring method

Comment: use regex (\d{10}$)

Comment: `/\d{10}$/.exec('+91-84040355236545')[0]`

Comment: @joyBlanks I just checked your rgx and it works

Comment: [*I have few solution for that*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57669934/1) - which ones? Please add to the question and explain what does not work for you. Maybe your solution is already the most optimized one.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had the solution of string.substring method

Comment: So add the code to the question and state what is wrong with it. It looks the most optimal given the current question. Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57670019/3832970) does not help you since you are already using `substring`.

Comment: Instead of the regex given use `(\d{5,10}$)` to get numbers of length 5 to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using **substrings**:

```
var number = "+91-84040355236545";
var lastTenDigitsNumber = number.substr(number.length - 10);
console.log(lastTenDigitsNumber);
```

A simpler solution is using **slice**:

```
var number = "+91-84040355236545";
console.log(number.slice(-10));
```

Another solution using a function and **RegEX**:

```
function extractTenDigits(number) {
  var rx = /(\d{10}$)/g;
  var arr = rx.exec(number);
  return arr[1]; 
}

var number = "+91-84040355236545";
console.log(extractTenDigits(number));
```

I did a simple benchmark and the best solution for small quantity of numbers is the one using **slice**.

If you provide more details I can provide a more tailored suggestion.

Comment: OP is requesting you to give the most optimized solution, so which one is it?

Comment: I would suggest slice because of simplicity and performances but we don't know much about the data / application context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) :

```
let str = "+91-84040355236545";
str.substr(str.length - 10  ,10);
```

Comment: OP is already using this code.

Comment: He wasn't when I posted this answer.